# Way to find if a vector is a subset of another vector including the order of that vector with repeated values in R

Tags: r, vector, subset

I want to find if a vector is a subset of another vector including that vectors order.
For example

```
A <- c("A","B","C","D","A","C")
B <- c("X","Z","A","B","C","D","A","C","K","Y")
True
```

A is found within B

```
A <- c("A","B","C","D","A","C")
B <- c("A","B","D","C","A","C")
False
```

A if not found in B

Answer (score 0):

You can try `grepl` + `paste0` like below

```
grepl(paste0(A,collapse = ""),paste0(B,collapse = ""))
```

or `grepl` + `toString`

```
grepl(toString(A),toString(B))
```

Comment: Great option! I think this cannot be simpler than `paste/toString`